# How to fix "TypeError: an integer is required (got type tuple)" in pygame?

Tags: python

I am making a snake game in pygame. However, I ran into a `TypeError` problem inside my `Snake` class object. To be specific it threw an error inside the `draw()` (class) and `blit()` (non-class) functions, telling me that *"an integer is required"* (got type tuple).

```
import pygame
import random

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))

class Snake(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, height, width, color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.color = color
        self.vel = 3

    def draw(self): # The problem happened here
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color, (self.x, self.y), (self.height, self.width))

    def auto_move(self):
        pass


def blit(): # The problem also happened here
    snake.draw()

snake = Snake(300, 300, 64, 64, (0, 255, 0))

run = True
while run:
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    blit()
    pygame.display.update()
```

The game is far from finish as I quickly ran to said error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color, (self.x, self.y, self.height, self.width))`. Rect argument need to be a single tuple of `(x, y, w, h)` rather than `(x, y)` and `(w, h)`

Comment: `(self.height, self.width)` is what you are providing to the `radius` argument per the docs, however the docs say it only accepts an `int or float`

Comment: The error message should give you a line number. Please identify the affected line. You also want to create a [mre], that is: create a copy and remove everything that is not required to trigger the same error.

Comment: Sum up: `pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color, (self.x, self.y), (self.height, self.width))` needs to be `pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color, (self.x, self.y, self.height, self.width))` and `snack` is not yet defined.

Answer (score 0):

**To use `pygame.draw.rect`, [the documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.rect) says that you must pass as arguments:**

- `surface`: in your case, `surface` is `screen`.
- `color`: [`pygame.Color`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/color.html#pygame.Color), `int` or `tuple` of length 3. In your case `self.color`.
- `rect`: [`pygame.Rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html)

**The `rect` argument can be as following:**

1. `pygame.Rect(left, top, width, height)`
2. `pygame.Rect((left, top), (width, height))`
3. `pygame.Rect(object)`

**So, you must type**

```py
    def draw(self, screen): # The problem no longer happen here
        rect = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, self.height, self.width)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color, rect)
```

---

### Second error

> `def blit(): # The problem also happened here`

`snack.draw(screen)` >>> ?????

Of course! Why are you typing this line ? There is no "snack" class...

### -- Edit --

Your question has been edited to do a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and the person who edited didn't remove this line - I'll do it

Comment: There was, I forgot to remove that line of code.